# Storing user events in backend

Tags: javascript

my javascript is horrible so I'm not sure if this is as straight forward as I'd hoped.

I'd like to track user clicks through mouse events on my website. I have some simple java script that does that. How do I go about making it so my backend can store this? Is it even possible.

Backend for now can be in anything what so ever :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log events in the background using Ajax calls. Most JS frameworks, such as jQuery make this quite simple to do.